# Program R create histogram of data from specified levels of multiple factors

Tags: r

I want to create histograms from selected data in a larger file.  Example data set structure as follows:

```
Column headers(values)
Trip (1,2,3,4)
Site (1,2)
Year (2013, 2104)
Amount (values range from 1 - 100)
```

For example, what code do I use to plot a histogram of values from `Amount` of only data from `Trip 1, Site 1, Year 2014`?

I got as far as `hist(Amount[Trip=="1"])`, but I don't know how to further specify which data I want it to use.

Answer (score 2):

You probably are looking for `&`, which ANDs logical vectors componentwise:

```
> nn <- 100
> Trip <- sample(1:4,nn,T)
> Site <- sample(1:2,nn,T)
> Amount <- runif(nn)
> hist(Amount[Trip==1 & Site==1])
```

Don't confuse `&` with `&&`! Look at `?"&&"` for more info.

You may want to read "An Introduction to R", which should be available as PDF under the "Help" menu entry of your R GUI.